# how to fix a daily updater in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a webpage that updates the information on the index page every day, the way it updates is through a simple function.

JS :

```
function date() {
var day = new date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = subS;
weekday[1] = subM;
weekday[2] = subT;
weekday[3] = subW;
weekday[4] = subT;
weekday[5] = subF;
weekday[6] = subSa;
}

function subM() {

var year = 'YR : 11 ';
var room = 'ROOM: DM8 ';
var teacher = 'TEACHER: K HA ';

var year = year;
var room = room;
var teacher = teacher;

var el = document.getElementById('year');
el.textContent = year;

var el = document.getElementById('room');
el.textContent = room;

var el = document.getElementById('teacher');
el.textContent = teacher;

}
```

My expected result was to make the function subM run in the function date on a weekday[1]

Comment: Should create new date with capital 'D', `day = new Date()`. Your `subM` function declares `var year` twice.  If you want `subM` to run right away you need to invoke it by calling it with parens, `weekday[0] = subS();`.  But doing this will overwrite each previous values of 'year', 'room', and 'teacher' element each time `weekday[i] = sub<S>();`.  You should probably instead keep a map of functions you want to run using the day of the week as a key and invoke the callback (or just store them as an object) to set the elements.

Answer (score -1):

Use an array to store what you want each day to display and use the current date's getDay function to get the [0-6] value to index into that array to get the object containing the data you want to display.

```
var dayValues = [
  { // subM as index 0
    year: 'YR : 11',
    room: 'ROOM: DM8',
    teacher: 'TEACHER: K HA'
  },
  { ... }, // index 1
  ...
  { ... } // index 6
};

function updateDay() {
  var day = new date();
  var dayInfo = dayValues[day.getDay()];

  var yearEl = document.getElementById('year');
  yearEl.textContent = dayInfo.year;

  var roomEl = document.getElementById('room');
  roomEl.textContent = dayInfo.room;

  var teacherEl = document.getElementById('teacher');
  teacherEl.textContent = dayInfo.teacher;
}
```

Comment: Drew could you please help me with this project? It would be really helpful in helping me learn more about javascript.

Comment: That's not exactly the purpose of Stack Overflow, but if you can provide a [minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with a specific issue that really goes a long way.